# Autocomplete textbox: How to reduce textsize?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have put an autocomplete box in a page with the following code:

```
 $(function() {
    var availableTags = ["Recharge",

        "Tea",
        "Coffee"

    ];
    $( ".extra" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
```

When I put T or C in the textbox, it gives autocomplete options with very huge text size. How can I change the font size in the autocomplete? How to add hover color to it?

Answer (score 0):

Find this is jQuery UI CSS (~line 156-157):

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
```

Add your preferred font size to there.

For Hover, just add this line into CSS:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a:hover { color: red !important; }
```

But personally I would prefer jQuery UI [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) downloads and edit from their UI

P.s: Chrome's "Inspect element" or firefox's (also on chrome) [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI only creates a `ul` list with the class `ui-autocomplete`. So you have just to adjust the font via CSS.